# How to Pass my object ids to my action method using Ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following field inside my asp.net mvc view:-

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.CheckBoxSelection, new { @value = item.TMSServerID.ToString() })
}
```

and i wrote the following jquery to select the values for the CheckBox if selected :-

```
$('body').on("click", "#transferSelectedServers", function () {
    var boxData = [];
    $("input[name='CheckBoxSelection']:checked").each(function () {
        boxData.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Content("~/Server/DeleteSelected")",
        data: { ids: boxData.join(",") }
    })
});
```

and i have the following Action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public string DeleteSelected(string ids)
```

but currently the values passed to my action method will be empty string.

Comment: first check boxData array's length before passing it to ajax. May be array has problem and length is zero

Comment: Not sure about not populating the array, but wouldn't it be easier to just pass the array and have the action method parameter as `public string DeleteSelected(int[] ids) {..`? - note you would need to set `traditional:true` in the ajax options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller contains the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute. Since you arent passing the antiforgery token with your ajax request you're receiving an error.

If you check your response body you will probably see the error.

So you have two options

1. Remove the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute
2. Keep the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` and pass the token over along with your ids

**Update**

Sending AntiForgeryToken using Ajax

Render the antiforgerytoken in your view by adding the following

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

This will generate a hidden field like this...

```
<input type="hidden" value="SSjplL_6t1bxDmb8qTdHcqX5ScafLxw4kmFMzc1dJ7T4kuXfL3aiDWIrwEjk9JKsUV4TGUsENKbRTRJ0W2zYLeHjmtCg02TZQBDevWeRYEA1" name="__RequestVerificationToken">
```

All you need to do is pass over that value using `__RequestVerificationToken` as the object name.

So your ajax call will look something like this now...

```
  var token = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Content("~/Server/DeleteSelected")",
        data: { ids: boxData.join(","), __RequestVerificationToken: token }
    })
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: you are right this is causing the problem, but is there a way to pass an antiforgry token using jquery ?